# Expects different model type than passed in MVC ASP.NET Site Error after deploying to azurewebsite

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting this error when I published the site to azurewebsite. However, site works just fine in my localhost. Please help. I have attached my code below. Please bear with me - I am very new to MVC.NET; and this is my first post in stackoverflow :). I am hoping to hear from experts.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type ".DataTranferObjects.FilteredViewDTO", but this dictionary requires a model item of type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[.DataTranferObjects.AllCountiesSuppyViewDTO]".
```

Code in my main view to render partial view:

```
@model ****.DataTranferObjects.FilteredViewDTO
@{Html.RenderPartial("_SupplyDetailPartial", Model);}
```

I am passing the FilteredViewDTO model in my partial view.

Code in my partial view:

```
@model ****.DataTranferObjects.FilteredViewDTO
@foreach (var item in Model.supplyViewDTO)
{
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountyName)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullTime)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PartTime)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)</td>
</tr>
}
```

Code in my FilteredViewDTO.cs:

```
public class FilteredViewDTO
{
    public List<AllCountiesSuppyViewDTO> supplyViewDTO { get; set; }
}
```

Code in my AllCountiesSupplyViewDTO.cs:

```
public class AllCountiesSuppyViewDTO
{
    public string CountyName { get; set; }
    public int? FullTime { get; set; }
    public int? PartTime { get; set; }
    public int? Total { get; set; }
}
```

Code in my Controller that returns view:

```
public ActionResult Main()
    {
        /*............*/

        var allCountiesSupplyData = GetAllCountiesSupplyData();

        return View("Main", "_Layout1", allCountiesSupplyData);
    }
```

Code in my GetAllCountiesSupplyData method:

```
private FilteredViewDTO GetAllCountiesSupplyData()
    {
        using (var dbContext = new DbDataContext())
        {
            /*........*/

            FilteredViewDTO fv = new FilteredViewDTO();
            fv.supplyViewDTO = (List<AllCountiesSuppyViewDTO>)results.ToList();              

            return fv;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this is working locally, but fails on deployment, maybe the razor page isn't being published correctly?  I only just yesterday had a deployment issue because a file was given a "Build Action" of "None" when it should have been "Content".

Comment: Thanks Brendan Green for replying. I checked the "Build Action" it is set to "Content" and I did pull the file via FTP to see if anything wrong - razor file looks good. I don't understand why I am getting this error when I am passing the exact model my partial view is expecting. Rather spending time to figure out the error, I created my own extension to return the exactly what my partial view does render. And after rendering the extension instead of partial view, it is working in azurewebsite.